# How to use repository pattern and dependency injection in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, laravel, dependency-injection, repository

I developed a system using Laravel, now i want to migrate the same system to NodeJS. In the Laravel i was using repository pattern ([this library](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)), so i had this scheme:

routes => controller => service => repository => (eloquent) model

Well, i've seen some libraries ([awilix](https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix), [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)) that could help me to do the task, but i'm having some doubts.

I structured the folders this way:

```
/server.js
/lib/config
/lib/routes
/lib/controllers
/lib/models
/lib/services
```

I would like some insight if i'm on the right path to build a huge app (the system will have more than 100 entities).

Other question, i'm not getting to use Dependency Injection through awilix, so i try something manual, but everytime i use DepartmentController like a class, i got this error:

```
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
const routes = require('./lib/routes/index'); // Rotas
app.use('/', routes);
```

**lib/controllers/index.js**

```
const departmentController = require('./DepartmentController');
module.exports = {
   departmentController
};
```

**lib/controllers/DepartmentController.js**

```
const Department = require('../models').Department;
const DepartmentService = require('../services/DepartmentService').DepartmentService;

module.exports = class DepartmentController {
  list(req, res) {
    return Department
      .all()
      .then(data => res.status(200).send(data))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
}
```

**lib/routes/index.js**

```
const routes = require('express').Router();
const department_routes = require('./DepartmentRoute');
routes.use('/api', department_routes);
module.exports = routes;
```

**lib/routes/DepartmentRoute.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const departmentController = require('../controllers').departmentController;

router.route('/departments').get(departmentController.list);  
module.exports = router;
```

**lib/models/Department.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Department = sequelize.define('Department', 
  { 
    // sequelize options and database fields, working fine
  }
  return Department;
};
```

**lib/services/DepartmentService.js**

```
const Department = require('../models').Department;

module.exports = class DepartmentService 
{
  constructor({ Department }) {
    this.departments = Department
  }

  findAll() {
    return this.departments.all();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you define your class here: lib/controllers/DepartmentController.js

but that class's method is not static. so you need to create an instance.

you should do this in lib/routes/DepartmentRoute.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const DepartmentController = require('../controllers').departmentController;

const departmentController = new DepartmentController();

router.route('/departments').get(departmentController.list);  
module.exports = router;
```